# Laravel if condition is match disable otherwise don't disable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to display option tags in a condition like if value is equals to 1 disable option with value 1. but if its not equal don't disable

I have tried as below, but i don't think that way is possable

```
<select class="form-control" required>
    @foreach($timeline as $value)

        @if ($value == '1' )
            <option disabled>1</option>  <!--  disable option 1 -->
        @elseif ( $value == '2')
            <option disabled>2</option>  <!-- disable option 2 -->
        @elseif ( $value == '6')
            <option disabled>6</option>  <!-- disable option 6 -->
        @else
            <option>1</option>  
            <option>2</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
        @endif

    @endforeach

    <option>8 pm </option>
    <option>9 pm </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try doing it like this:

```
<option {{ $value == '6' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>6</option>
```

What this does is, if the value equals 6, it's going to echo `disabled` in that specific place. If it's some other value it's going to still call echo, but with an empty string which results in no output and thus does not disable anything.

Comment: FIrst Thanks for help, this throw error. but i tried like this
`<option ( $value == '6' ? : 'disabled' : '' )>6</option>`  this don't give error but this make loop

Comment: @sarwanthapa Fixed a minor syntax error in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="form-control" id="optvalue" name="optvalue">

               @foreach($timeline as $value)

                  @if ($value->id == '1' )
                  <option value="1" {{ (old('optvalue') == 1) ? "disabled" : "" }}>1</option>  <!--  disable option 1 -->
                  @elseif ( $value->id == '2')
                  <option value="2" {{ (old('optvalue') == 2) ? "disabled" : "" }}>2</option>  <!-- disable option 2 -->
                  @elseif ( $value->id == '6')
                  <option value="6" {{ (old('optvalue') == 6) ? "disabled" : "" }}>6</option>  <!-- disable option 6 -->
                  @else
                  <option>1</option>  
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>6</option>
                  <option>7</option>
                  @endif
              @endforeach
                  <option>8 pm </option>
                  <option>9 pm </option>
                </select>
```